# Seeking value of an object with an integer name burried in an array (js)

Tags: javascript, json

So Im trying to see if there is an image in "images" The images are stored as an object with a name of an integer inside of an array. I can't get into the array and see if 0 (the first image) is inside without getting an error. I already tried bracket notation, with and without quotes. I just need to see if the image exists. If it doesnt, there would be no integer named objects. Thank you.. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$scope.images= [];
var syncArray = $firebaseArray(spotReference.child("images"));
$scope.images = syncArray;
console.log(syncArray); //returns array (image attached of console)

var imgThr = syncArray.indexOf(0,0);
         console.log(imgThr); // broken, tried with/without quotes
```

[image]

Comment: [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) does not take an index at first parameter but an object that you're looking for

Comment: `var imgThr = syncArray[0] ? syncArray[0].image : '';`

Comment: @MysterX, it looks like that just console.logs inside the single quote regardless of the objects inside array.

Comment: @MysterX, thank you for response. Could you elaborate a bit on this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

from your question, if there is no image then there will not be objects inside that array. Then we can check length property of array:

```
if(syncArray.length > 0) {
```

}

Or if you want to access the image property then you need to use :

```
if(syncArray[0].image) {
}
```

Comment: thats not working. I just want to console.log if there are NO images. No luck with that

Comment: What will be the structure of array if there is no image? will it be empty contains the object with null properties?

Comment: it contains other objects but only images are named with a number